# Kafka consumer UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, producer-consumer

I have a microservice running kafka consumer group subscribing to two different topic(say topic1 and topic2). Verified the subscription with below command -
`bin\windows\kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group mygroupId`

It seems to be working fine.

However, the service logs are producing warning as -
`[Consumer clientId=myclientId, groupId=mygroupId] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2369423 : {topic1,topic2=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}`

I have verified topic names and they do exist. Also tried running a producer and consumer via console, and the messages are being published and received successfully.
Also verified the acl on the topic with below command and the output was empty.
`kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=zookeeperhost:2181 --list --topic topic1`

Can someone please help as why this UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION error might be coming?

Comment: The topic named `topic1,topic2` does not exist. The parameter passed to the [KafkaConsumer.subscribe](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#subscribe-java.util.Collection-) method is a String Collection where each element is a topic name.

Comment: Yes. That we do are passing comma separated topic names in kafkaconsumer.subscribe and the topics also exist with the same name. But still getting this error.